# How to get the first line of span in php?

Tags: php, html

I am looking for a way to get each line of a span tag in php.
I have attempted to use **explode** and **strpos** but I can't get these to work.

I have a line of markup that is formatted like this:

```
<span>
LINE 1
<br/>
9.00am
<br/>
Description: this can be quite a long piece of text.
</span>
```

I need to have seperate variables for each line that I can reference later, these need to have the full contents of that line, but only that line.

How can I extract each line into a seperate variable without knowing the length of the individual lines?

There are 3 lines in text that I am interested in so ideally the end result will be:

```
$line1 = "LINE 1"
$line2 = "9.00am"
$line3 = "Description: this can be quite a long piece of text"
```

Comment: What do you mean by "get each line of span tag"? Get all the content inside that span tag, is that it?

Comment: I need to have 3 variables as im interested in the first 3 lines as above.
End result should return the following:

$line1 = "LINE 1";
$line2 = "9.00am";
$line3 = "Description: this can be quite a long piece of text";

Thats based on the text provided in question above.

Comment: What is your expected Result?

Comment: As above. I have also edited the question to include the expected result.

Comment: How are you defining your span tag initially? Is it written statically on an html document or is it defined as a variable and then displayed later onto the page in php?

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to use `explode` or `strpos` on HTML. Use a parser so the elements are correctly read, then you can use a regex on the nodevalue and its rendered content to get each line:

```
<?php
$html = '<span>
LINE 1
<br/>
9.00am
<br/>
Description: this can be quite a long piece of text.
</span>';
$dom = new domdocument();
$dom->loadhtml($html);
$spans = $dom->getelementsbytagname('span');
foreach($spans as $span){
    $lines = preg_split('/\v+/', $span->nodeValue, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
    print_r($lines);
}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => LINE 1
    [1] => 9.00am
    [2] => Description: this can be quite a long piece of text.
)
```

This answer presumes `Description` doesn't have new lines in it. If it does you will need to alter the pattern. Currently it splits on at least one vertical space (aka a new line).

Comment: Sadly, I don't see people using built-in DOM classes very often. Your solution is very clean.